# Compare two different urls using Linux

Tags: linux, diff

Am I able to compare two different urls/websites without downloading the file first using `wget` or something similar first.  I tried the following, but received the below error.

```
[root@desktop ~]# diff http://www.example.net/index.php http://www.example.com/index.php
diff: http://www.example.net/index.php: No such file or directory
diff: http://www.example.com/index.php: No such file or directory
[root@desktop ~]#
```

Comment: diff works only with files, not with URLs

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Is there a different command which would work with urls?

Comment: Not that I know, but I'm not a Linux specialist. You could make a small script that downloads both URLs to /tmp and the laucnhes diff on those files.

Comment: Actually you could use `diff` with process substitution. `diff  <(echo "http://www.example.com/index.php" ) <(echo "http://www.example.net/index.php")` (Do you want to compare urls or the page itself ?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course you can use `curl`, although it is a bit strange:

```
diff <(curl url1) <(curl url2)
```

In your case:

```
diff <(curl http://www.example.net/index.php) <(curl http://www.example.com/index.php)
```

Note you can use `curl -s` for a cleaner diff execution.

Comment: Thanks fedorqui,  Is `curl` preferred over Paulloz's example with `echo`?

Comment: `curl` will compare pages itself, while `echo` the strings.

Comment: OK, I'm interested @fedorqui. Why is using curl to do diff  'a bit strange'?

Comment: @Rich I said "a bit strange" because of the syntax. We normally say `diff file1 file2`, whereas using [process substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31703275/1983854) looks a bit weird the first. But it is completely valid and a very useful way to do it once you learn it : )